# Working with return url and cookie authentication in asp.net core

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, asp.net-core-2.2

Im using cookie authentication in asp.net core 2.2 along with SSO. When user enter our site url for e.g somesite.com, its redirected to SSOLogin, and on the SSO callback i get user data then I am redirecting user to Home/Index. I want when user enter somesite.com/employee/getemployees it should be redirect to url entered by user instead to home/index. As SSO is implemented, user doesnt require to submit login details so i cant use mechanism of return url. Could anyone suggest what are other approaches and how this can be achieved? Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. remove the `RedirectToAction(..)`  at the last line.  2. Save the ReturnUrl in TempData/Cookie when redirecting the User to SSO. 3. Sign in the user like `HttpContext.SignInAsync(...,..., new AuthenticationProperties{  ..., RedirectUri=<the-url-from-TempData> })`

Comment: As a side note, please replace the image (screenshot) with text (codes).  See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557)

Comment: You can take a look at the open source implementation of oidc of [IdentityServer](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/big_picture.html) and the [source code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4).